# Elmah getting stuck in default route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I added Elmah.MVC to my MVC-site, but when access /elmah, my site gets stuck in a redirect loop /elmah?culture=en - which I reckon is because of my one route config entry:

```
    public class  RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Home", action = "SetCulture", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

How should I modify RouteConfig to make /elmah display correctly? Or am I looking at the wrong place?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused by a class called CultureAwareControllerActivator that implements IControllerActivator

My knowledge is limited, but it seems that this class (which I added myself) connects to the request when the controller is activated and decides whether or not to modify and redirect.

```
public class CultureAwareControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        string cultureName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string;

        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        if (cultureName == null)
            cultureName = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null && requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0
                ? requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]
                : null; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe


        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName && (string) requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] != "Elmah")
        {

            // Force a valid culture in the URL
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant(); // lower case too

            // Redirect user
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(requestContext.RouteData.Values);
        }


        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```